# how can i stop my header overflowing with lorem https://jsfiddle.net/joshbjs/r9scauqe/3/

Tags: html, css, layout, header, navbar

```css
.box {
  border-bottom: 10px solid #ccc;
  padding: 20px;
  color: indianred;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 3000px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>css 201</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/202.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="box">
    this is a header
  </div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente fugiat repudiandae excepturi voluptatibus sunt ipsum provident? Blanditiis natus minus sint in architecto dolorum ab, quisquam cupiditate? Aspernatur blanditiis repellendus ullam?</p>
</body>

</html>
```

the problem I am having is that my lorem is overflowing into my header/navbar.

[here is a screenshot in chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZsj0.png)

[here is a screenshot of my html and css code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSUTo.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you're using `position: fixed;` and the positional attributes on your header, so that box is going to overlap other elements. Unless you have a reason for doing that that you didn't specify in your question, you can just remove those attributes.

See here for more info on `position`: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp

```css
.box {
  border-bottom: 10px solid #ccc;
  padding: 20px;
  color: indianred;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
}

body {
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 3000px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>css 201</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/202.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="box">
    this is a header
  </div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente fugiat repudiandae excepturi voluptatibus sunt ipsum provident? Blanditiis natus minus sint in architecto dolorum ab, quisquam cupiditate? Aspernatur blanditiis repellendus ullam?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente fugiat repudiandae excepturi voluptatibus sunt ipsum provident? Blanditiis natus minus sint in architecto dolorum ab, quisquam cupiditate? Aspernatur blanditiis repellendus ullam?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente fugiat repudiandae excepturi voluptatibus sunt ipsum provident? Blanditiis natus minus sint in architecto dolorum ab, quisquam cupiditate? Aspernatur blanditiis repellendus ullam?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente fugiat repudiandae excepturi voluptatibus sunt ipsum provident? Blanditiis natus minus sint in architecto dolorum ab, quisquam cupiditate? Aspernatur blanditiis repellendus ullam?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente fugiat repudiandae excepturi voluptatibus sunt ipsum provident? Blanditiis natus minus sint in architecto dolorum ab, quisquam cupiditate? Aspernatur blanditiis repellendus ullam?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente fugiat repudiandae excepturi voluptatibus sunt ipsum provident? Blanditiis natus minus sint in architecto dolorum ab, quisquam cupiditate? Aspernatur blanditiis repellendus ullam?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente fugiat repudiandae excepturi voluptatibus sunt ipsum provident? Blanditiis natus minus sint in architecto dolorum ab, quisquam cupiditate? Aspernatur blanditiis repellendus ullam?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente fugiat repudiandae excepturi voluptatibus sunt ipsum provident? Blanditiis natus minus sint in architecto dolorum ab, quisquam cupiditate? Aspernatur blanditiis repellendus ullam?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente fugiat repudiandae excepturi voluptatibus sunt ipsum provident? Blanditiis natus minus sint in architecto dolorum ab, quisquam cupiditate? Aspernatur blanditiis repellendus ullam?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente fugiat repudiandae excepturi voluptatibus sunt ipsum provident? Blanditiis natus minus sint in architecto dolorum ab, quisquam cupiditate? Aspernatur blanditiis repellendus ullam?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente fugiat repudiandae excepturi voluptatibus sunt ipsum provident? Blanditiis natus minus sint in architecto dolorum ab, quisquam cupiditate? Aspernatur blanditiis repellendus ullam?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente fugiat repudiandae excepturi voluptatibus sunt ipsum provident? Blanditiis natus minus sint in architecto dolorum ab, quisquam cupiditate? Aspernatur blanditiis repellendus ullam?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente fugiat repudiandae excepturi voluptatibus sunt ipsum provident? Blanditiis natus minus sint in architecto dolorum ab, quisquam cupiditate? Aspernatur blanditiis repellendus ullam?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente fugiat repudiandae excepturi voluptatibus sunt ipsum provident? Blanditiis natus minus sint in architecto dolorum ab, quisquam cupiditate? Aspernatur blanditiis repellendus ullam?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente fugiat repudiandae excepturi voluptatibus sunt ipsum provident? Blanditiis natus minus sint in architecto dolorum ab, quisquam cupiditate? Aspernatur blanditiis repellendus ullam?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente fugiat repudiandae excepturi voluptatibus sunt ipsum provident? Blanditiis natus minus sint in architecto dolorum ab, quisquam cupiditate? Aspernatur blanditiis repellendus ullam?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente fugiat repudiandae excepturi voluptatibus sunt ipsum provident? Blanditiis natus minus sint in architecto dolorum ab, quisquam cupiditate? Aspernatur blanditiis repellendus ullam?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente fugiat repudiandae excepturi voluptatibus sunt ipsum provident? Blanditiis natus minus sint in architecto dolorum ab, quisquam cupiditate? Aspernatur blanditiis repellendus ullam?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente fugiat repudiandae excepturi voluptatibus sunt ipsum provident? Blanditiis natus minus sint in architecto dolorum ab, quisquam cupiditate? Aspernatur blanditiis repellendus ullam?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente fugiat repudiandae excepturi voluptatibus sunt ipsum provident? Blanditiis natus minus sint in architecto dolorum ab, quisquam cupiditate? Aspernatur blanditiis repellendus ullam?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente fugiat repudiandae excepturi voluptatibus sunt ipsum provident? Blanditiis natus minus sint in architecto dolorum ab, quisquam cupiditate? Aspernatur blanditiis repellendus ullam?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente fugiat repudiandae excepturi voluptatibus sunt ipsum provident? Blanditiis natus minus sint in architecto dolorum ab, quisquam cupiditate? Aspernatur blanditiis repellendus ullam?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente fugiat repudiandae excepturi voluptatibus sunt ipsum provident? Blanditiis natus minus sint in architecto dolorum ab, quisquam cupiditate? Aspernatur blanditiis repellendus ullam?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente fugiat repudiandae excepturi voluptatibus sunt ipsum provident? Blanditiis natus minus sint in architecto dolorum ab, quisquam cupiditate? Aspernatur blanditiis repellendus ullam?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente fugiat repudiandae excepturi voluptatibus sunt ipsum provident? Blanditiis natus minus sint in architecto dolorum ab, quisquam cupiditate? Aspernatur blanditiis repellendus ullam?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente fugiat repudiandae excepturi voluptatibus sunt ipsum provident? Blanditiis natus minus sint in architecto dolorum ab, quisquam cupiditate? Aspernatur blanditiis repellendus ullam?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente fugiat repudiandae excepturi voluptatibus sunt ipsum provident? Blanditiis natus minus sint in architecto dolorum ab, quisquam cupiditate? Aspernatur blanditiis repellendus ullam?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente fugiat repudiandae excepturi voluptatibus sunt ipsum provident? Blanditiis natus minus sint in architecto dolorum ab, quisquam cupiditate? Aspernatur blanditiis repellendus ullam?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente fugiat repudiandae excepturi voluptatibus sunt ipsum provident? Blanditiis natus minus sint in architecto dolorum ab, quisquam cupiditate? Aspernatur blanditiis repellendus ullam?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente fugiat repudiandae excepturi voluptatibus sunt ipsum provident? Blanditiis natus minus sint in architecto dolorum ab, quisquam cupiditate? Aspernatur blanditiis repellendus ullam?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente fugiat repudiandae excepturi voluptatibus sunt ipsum provident? Blanditiis natus minus sint in architecto dolorum ab, quisquam cupiditate? Aspernatur blanditiis repellendus ullam?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente fugiat repudiandae excepturi voluptatibus sunt ipsum provident? Blanditiis natus minus sint in architecto dolorum ab, quisquam cupiditate? Aspernatur blanditiis repellendus ullam?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente fugiat repudiandae excepturi voluptatibus sunt ipsum provident? Blanditiis natus minus sint in architecto dolorum ab, quisquam cupiditate? Aspernatur blanditiis repellendus ullam?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente fugiat repudiandae excepturi voluptatibus sunt ipsum provident? Blanditiis natus minus sint in architecto dolorum ab, quisquam cupiditate? Aspernatur blanditiis repellendus ullam?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente fugiat repudiandae excepturi voluptatibus sunt ipsum provident? Blanditiis natus minus sint in architecto dolorum ab, quisquam cupiditate? Aspernatur blanditiis repellendus ullam?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente fugiat repudiandae excepturi voluptatibus sunt ipsum provident? Blanditiis natus minus sint in architecto dolorum ab, quisquam cupiditate? Aspernatur blanditiis repellendus ullam?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente fugiat repudiandae excepturi voluptatibus sunt ipsum provident? Blanditiis natus minus sint in architecto dolorum ab, quisquam cupiditate? Aspernatur blanditiis repellendus ullam?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente fugiat repudiandae excepturi voluptatibus sunt ipsum provident? Blanditiis natus minus sint in architecto dolorum ab, quisquam cupiditate? Aspernatur blanditiis repellendus ullam?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente fugiat repudiandae excepturi voluptatibus sunt ipsum provident? Blanditiis natus minus sint in architecto dolorum ab, quisquam cupiditate? Aspernatur blanditiis repellendus ullam?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente fugiat repudiandae excepturi voluptatibus sunt ipsum provident? Blanditiis natus minus sint in architecto dolorum ab, quisquam cupiditate? Aspernatur blanditiis repellendus ullam?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente fugiat repudiandae excepturi voluptatibus sunt ipsum provident? Blanditiis natus minus sint in architecto dolorum ab, quisquam cupiditate? Aspernatur blanditiis repellendus ullam?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente fugiat repudiandae excepturi voluptatibus sunt ipsum provident? Blanditiis natus minus sint in architecto dolorum ab, quisquam cupiditate? Aspernatur blanditiis repellendus ullam?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente fugiat repudiandae excepturi voluptatibus sunt ipsum provident? Blanditiis natus minus sint in architecto dolorum ab, quisquam cupiditate? Aspernatur blanditiis repellendus ullam?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente fugiat repudiandae excepturi voluptatibus sunt ipsum provident? Blanditiis natus minus sint in architecto dolorum ab, quisquam cupiditate? Aspernatur blanditiis repellendus ullam?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente fugiat repudiandae excepturi voluptatibus sunt ipsum provident? Blanditiis natus minus sint in architecto dolorum ab, quisquam cupiditate? Aspernatur blanditiis repellendus ullam?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente fugiat repudiandae excepturi voluptatibus sunt ipsum provident? Blanditiis natus minus sint in architecto dolorum ab, quisquam cupiditate? Aspernatur blanditiis repellendus ullam?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente fugiat repudiandae excepturi voluptatibus sunt ipsum provident? Blanditiis natus minus sint in architecto dolorum ab, quisquam cupiditate? Aspernatur blanditiis repellendus ullam?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente fugiat repudiandae excepturi voluptatibus sunt ipsum provident? Blanditiis natus minus sint in architecto dolorum ab, quisquam cupiditate? Aspernatur blanditiis repellendus ullam?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente fugiat repudiandae excepturi voluptatibus sunt ipsum provident? Blanditiis natus minus sint in architecto dolorum ab, quisquam cupiditate? Aspernatur blanditiis repellendus ullam?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente fugiat repudiandae excepturi voluptatibus sunt ipsum provident? Blanditiis natus minus sint in architecto dolorum ab, quisquam cupiditate? Aspernatur blanditiis repellendus ullam?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente fugiat repudiandae excepturi voluptatibus sunt ipsum provident? Blanditiis natus minus sint in architecto dolorum ab, quisquam cupiditate? Aspernatur blanditiis repellendus ullam?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente fugiat repudiandae excepturi voluptatibus sunt ipsum provident? Blanditiis natus minus sint in architecto dolorum ab, quisquam cupiditate? Aspernatur blanditiis repellendus ullam?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente fugiat repudiandae excepturi voluptatibus sunt ipsum provident? Blanditiis natus minus sint in architecto dolorum ab, quisquam cupiditate? Aspernatur blanditiis repellendus ullam?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente fugiat repudiandae excepturi voluptatibus sunt ipsum provident? Blanditiis natus minus sint in architecto dolorum ab, quisquam cupiditate? Aspernatur blanditiis repellendus ullam?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente fugiat repudiandae excepturi voluptatibus sunt ipsum provident? Blanditiis natus minus sint in architecto dolorum ab, quisquam cupiditate? Aspernatur blanditiis repellendus ullam?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente fugiat repudiandae excepturi voluptatibus sunt ipsum provident? Blanditiis natus minus sint in architecto dolorum ab, quisquam cupiditate? Aspernatur blanditiis repellendus ullam?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente fugiat repudiandae excepturi voluptatibus sunt ipsum provident? Blanditiis natus minus sint in architecto dolorum ab, quisquam cupiditate? Aspernatur blanditiis repellendus ullam?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente fugiat repudiandae excepturi voluptatibus sunt ipsum provident? Blanditiis natus minus sint in architecto dolorum ab, quisquam cupiditate? Aspernatur blanditiis repellendus ullam?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente fugiat repudiandae excepturi voluptatibus sunt ipsum provident? Blanditiis natus minus sint in architecto dolorum ab, quisquam cupiditate? Aspernatur blanditiis repellendus ullam?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente fugiat repudiandae excepturi voluptatibus sunt ipsum provident? Blanditiis natus minus sint in architecto dolorum ab, quisquam cupiditate? Aspernatur blanditiis repellendus ullam?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente fugiat repudiandae excepturi voluptatibus sunt ipsum provident? Blanditiis natus minus sint in architecto dolorum ab, quisquam cupiditate? Aspernatur blanditiis repellendus ullam?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente fugiat repudiandae excepturi voluptatibus sunt ipsum provident? Blanditiis natus minus sint in architecto dolorum ab, quisquam cupiditate? Aspernatur blanditiis repellendus ullam?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente fugiat repudiandae excepturi voluptatibus sunt ipsum provident? Blanditiis natus minus sint in architecto dolorum ab, quisquam cupiditate? Aspernatur blanditiis repellendus ullam?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente fugiat repudiandae excepturi voluptatibus sunt ipsum provident? Blanditiis natus minus sint in architecto dolorum ab, quisquam cupiditate? Aspernatur blanditiis repellendus ullam?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente fugiat repudiandae excepturi voluptatibus sunt ipsum provident? Blanditiis natus minus sint in architecto dolorum ab, quisquam cupiditate? Aspernatur blanditiis repellendus ullam?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente fugiat repudiandae excepturi voluptatibus sunt ipsum provident? Blanditiis natus minus sint in architecto dolorum ab, quisquam cupiditate? Aspernatur blanditiis repellendus ullam?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente fugiat repudiandae excepturi voluptatibus sunt ipsum provident? Blanditiis natus minus sint in architecto dolorum ab, quisquam cupiditate? Aspernatur blanditiis repellendus ullam?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente fugiat repudiandae excepturi voluptatibus sunt ipsum provident? Blanditiis natus minus sint in architecto dolorum ab, quisquam cupiditate? Aspernatur blanditiis repellendus ullam?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente fugiat repudiandae excepturi voluptatibus sunt ipsum provident? Blanditiis natus minus sint in architecto dolorum ab, quisquam cupiditate? Aspernatur blanditiis repellendus ullam?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente fugiat repudiandae excepturi voluptatibus sunt ipsum provident? Blanditiis natus minus sint in architecto dolorum ab, quisquam cupiditate? Aspernatur blanditiis repellendus ullam?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente fugiat repudiandae excepturi voluptatibus sunt ipsum provident? Blanditiis natus minus sint in architecto dolorum ab, quisquam cupiditate? Aspernatur blanditiis repellendus ullam?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente fugiat repudiandae excepturi voluptatibus sunt ipsum provident? Blanditiis natus minus sint in architecto dolorum ab, quisquam cupiditate? Aspernatur blanditiis repellendus ullam?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente fugiat repudiandae excepturi voluptatibus sunt ipsum provident? Blanditiis natus minus sint in architecto dolorum ab, quisquam cupiditate? Aspernatur blanditiis repellendus ullam?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente fugiat repudiandae excepturi voluptatibus sunt ipsum provident? Blanditiis natus minus sint in architecto dolorum ab, quisquam cupiditate? Aspernatur blanditiis repellendus ullam?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente fugiat repudiandae excepturi voluptatibus sunt ipsum provident? Blanditiis natus minus sint in architecto dolorum ab, quisquam cupiditate? Aspernatur blanditiis repellendus ullam?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente fugiat repudiandae excepturi voluptatibus sunt ipsum provident? Blanditiis natus minus sint in architecto dolorum ab, quisquam cupiditate? Aspernatur blanditiis repellendus ullam?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente fugiat repudiandae excepturi voluptatibus sunt ipsum provident? Blanditiis natus minus sint in architecto dolorum ab, quisquam cupiditate? Aspernatur blanditiis repellendus ullam?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente fugiat repudiandae excepturi voluptatibus sunt ipsum provident? Blanditiis natus minus sint in architecto dolorum ab, quisquam cupiditate? Aspernatur blanditiis repellendus ullam?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente fugiat repudiandae excepturi voluptatibus sunt ipsum provident? Blanditiis natus minus sint in architecto dolorum ab, quisquam cupiditate? Aspernatur blanditiis repellendus ullam?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente fugiat repudiandae excepturi voluptatibus sunt ipsum provident? Blanditiis natus minus sint in architecto dolorum ab, quisquam cupiditate? Aspernatur blanditiis repellendus ullam?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente fugiat repudiandae excepturi voluptatibus sunt ipsum provident? Blanditiis natus minus sint in architecto dolorum ab, quisquam cupiditate? Aspernatur blanditiis repellendus ullam?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente fugiat repudiandae excepturi voluptatibus sunt ipsum provident? Blanditiis natus minus sint in architecto dolorum ab, quisquam cupiditate? Aspernatur blanditiis repellendus ullam?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente fugiat repudiandae excepturi voluptatibus sunt ipsum provident? Blanditiis natus minus sint in architecto dolorum ab, quisquam cupiditate? Aspernatur blanditiis repellendus ullam?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente fugiat repudiandae excepturi voluptatibus sunt ipsum provident? Blanditiis natus minus sint in architecto dolorum ab, quisquam cupiditate? Aspernatur blanditiis repellendus ullam?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente fugiat repudiandae excepturi voluptatibus sunt ipsum provident? Blanditiis natus minus sint in architecto dolorum ab, quisquam cupiditate? Aspernatur blanditiis repellendus ullam?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente fugiat repudiandae excepturi voluptatibus sunt ipsum provident? Blanditiis natus minus sint in architecto dolorum ab, quisquam cupiditate? Aspernatur blanditiis repellendus ullam?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente fugiat repudiandae excepturi voluptatibus sunt ipsum provident? Blanditiis natus minus sint in architecto dolorum ab, quisquam cupiditate? Aspernatur blanditiis repellendus ullam?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente fugiat repudiandae excepturi voluptatibus sunt ipsum provident? Blanditiis natus minus sint in architecto dolorum ab, quisquam cupiditate? Aspernatur blanditiis repellendus ullam?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente fugiat repudiandae excepturi voluptatibus sunt ipsum provident? Blanditiis natus minus sint in architecto dolorum ab, quisquam cupiditate? Aspernatur blanditiis repellendus ullam?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente fugiat repudiandae excepturi voluptatibus sunt ipsum provident? Blanditiis natus minus sint in architecto dolorum ab, quisquam cupiditate? Aspernatur blanditiis repellendus ullam?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente fugiat repudiandae excepturi voluptatibus sunt ipsum provident? Blanditiis natus minus sint in architecto dolorum ab, quisquam cupiditate? Aspernatur blanditiis repellendus ullam?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente fugiat repudiandae excepturi voluptatibus sunt ipsum provident? Blanditiis natus minus sint in architecto dolorum ab, quisquam cupiditate? Aspernatur blanditiis repellendus ullam?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente fugiat repudiandae excepturi voluptatibus sunt ipsum provident? Blanditiis natus minus sint in architecto dolorum ab, quisquam cupiditate? Aspernatur blanditiis repellendus ullam?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente fugiat repudiandae excepturi voluptatibus sunt ipsum provident? Blanditiis natus minus sint in architecto dolorum ab, quisquam cupiditate? Aspernatur blanditiis repellendus ullam?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente fugiat repudiandae excepturi voluptatibus sunt ipsum provident? Blanditiis natus minus sint in architecto dolorum ab, quisquam cupiditate? Aspernatur blanditiis repellendus ullam?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente fugiat repudiandae excepturi voluptatibus sunt ipsum provident? Blanditiis natus minus sint in architecto dolorum ab, quisquam cupiditate? Aspernatur blanditiis repellendus ullam?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente fugiat repudiandae excepturi voluptatibus sunt ipsum provident? Blanditiis natus minus sint in architecto dolorum ab, quisquam cupiditate? Aspernatur blanditiis repellendus ullam?</p>




</body>

</html>
```

Comment: hi i have tried removing the atts but it is still not working. i am wanting to keep the fixed position so when i scroll it stays with me.

Comment: @JoshBrook Then you want to use position: sticky with z-index and a background-color defined so the text scrolls under it. See updated snippet above

Comment: thanks, it worked but I had to take z-index out

Answer (score 0):

```css
.box{
  border-bottom: 10px solid #ccc;
  padding: 20px;
  color: indianred;
  position: sticky;
  background: cornflowerblue;
  top: 0;
}

body{
  background: cornflowerblue;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 3000px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="box">
    This is a header
  </div>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Delectus nisi amet dicta laborum cupiditate tempora suscipit, magni vel eligendi inventore ex nihil doloremque porro quisquam laboriosam similique fugiat. Consectetur, enim!
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Quae at nesciunt earum odio id, ad praesentium. Minima culpa ducimus voluptate reiciendis qui! Accusantium, corporis officia! Quasi accusantium facere excepturi delectus.
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit mollitia corrupti iure nulla tempore laboriosam laudantium incidunt, magnam veniam exercitationem commodi quos eaque harum beatae libero provident! Numquam, culpa fugiat!
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequuntur molestias hic deleniti nobis sint iste minus at debitis similique, doloribus sit, rerum dicta eius voluptas corrupti laboriosam repellendus recusandae aliquam?
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Porro, harum a! Recusandae illum ipsa iste voluptatum cupiditate, autem, rerum molestias facilis blanditiis minus, nesciunt incidunt. Amet dicta harum perferendis autem!
  </p>
    <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Delectus nisi amet dicta laborum cupiditate tempora suscipit, magni vel eligendi inventore ex nihil doloremque porro quisquam laboriosam similique fugiat. Consectetur, enim!
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Quae at nesciunt earum odio id, ad praesentium. Minima culpa ducimus voluptate reiciendis qui! Accusantium, corporis officia! Quasi accusantium facere excepturi delectus.
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit mollitia corrupti iure nulla tempore laboriosam laudantium incidunt, magnam veniam exercitationem commodi quos eaque harum beatae libero provident! Numquam, culpa fugiat!
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequuntur molestias hic deleniti nobis sint iste minus at debitis similique, doloribus sit, rerum dicta eius voluptas corrupti laboriosam repellendus recusandae aliquam?
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Porro, harum a! Recusandae illum ipsa iste voluptatum cupiditate, autem, rerum molestias facilis blanditiis minus, nesciunt incidunt. Amet dicta harum perferendis autem!
  </p>
</body>
</html>
```

remove `position: fixed;` from `.box`
If you really need that then use

```css
.box{
   position: sticky;
   background: cornflowerblue;
   top: 0;
}
```

NB: please try to post your code. We need to type all the code to debug then.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/joshbjs/wx4j8fzp/4/

Comment: Yeah I know, But add some codes to your post. It catches eye fast.

Comment: thanks, it's working how I want it too now :)

Comment: ok, will do in the future thanks

Comment: If that fixed your problem then give a upvote and check the solved √ icon